# Portable alternative to execvpe

Tags: c, linux, libc

The `execvpe` function is a GNU extension. If I want my code to e portable to non-gnu libcs, how can I change an `execvpe` call to be portable?

`execvp` doesn't set the environment of the new program, and `execle` poth doesn't allow passing an array as the argument and doesn't try to resolve the executable from `PATH`.

Comment: Well the implementation is open-source, you can look at it to see what it does and do something similar yourself.

Comment: https://got.abiscuola.org/cgi-bin/gotweb/gotweb?path=zc-portable&action=blob&commit=f9d892c49a11d9c8464c208da8e7ddd8b7a8336a&file=execvpe.c&folder= <- I think this is some openbsd compatibility layer? Basically does path lookup + execve.

Comment: or in "musl libc", see https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/process/execvp.c#n9

Comment: The `exec*e()` functions are a bit of superfluous syntactic sugar, which is why they're not universally implemented.  Just set `environ` directly.  Construct the new environment array, and instead of passing it as an argument to an `exec*e()` function, just do `environ = newEnvArray; exec...();`

Comment: Looking at the implementation in glibc actually wasn't that helpful, because the other exec* functions that respect PATH are actually implemented using execvpe (because it is more general).  execvpe does call the execve system call, but the code for finding the executable using PATH is non-trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `environ` directly.

Per [the POSIX `exec()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) (bolding mine):

> ... In addition, the following variable, which must be declared by the user if it is to be used directly:
>
> ```
> extern char **environ;
> ```
>
> is initialized as a pointer to an array of character pointers to the environment strings. The `argv` and `environ` arrays are each terminated by a null pointer. The null pointer terminating the `argv` array is not counted in `argc`.
>
> **Applications can change the entire environment in a single operation by assigning the `environ` variable to point to an array of character pointers to the new environment strings.** ...

So instead of

```
exec...e( ...., myNewEnv );
```

you can do

```
extern char **environ;

   .
   .
   .

environ = myNewEnv;
exec...(...);
```